# Minimize-in-place - Do I need a custom framework

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, nswindow, appkit, nsapplication

I want to create a system wide minimize-in-place feature that occurs when double-clicking the title bar of any visible window in layer 0.

It seems that this would be a really simple feature to re-implement... When a  title-bar is double-clicked, just draw the title bar only. That's it.  The problem is implimenting it in all applications. I think it requires writting a custom framework to override the behavior in AppKit? Maybe NSApplication, NSWindow or NSView?

**How can I recreate minimize-in-place?**
Is a framework my only choice? If I create a framework, can I replace the behavior of minimize in 3rd party apps?

Which framework do I need to override in order to intercept and recreate the default behavior of the minimize button?

**More about minimize-in-place:**
I am familiar with WindowShade by Unsanity, this is exactly what I  want to create. Supposedly unsanity is working on a Lion version, but  their track record is bismal. Minimize-in-place was a system feature way  back in the days of OS 7 or 8. I have tried other utilities that try to  replace this feature, and there aren't any that do minimize-in-place at  a core system level like it needs to be done. Please don't offer  utitlity suggestions, I am going to build my own.

**I have built an Application that recreates minimize-in-place, but it's not good enough.**
My Application semi-successfully recreates minimize-in-place by putting "placeholder" windows (belonging to my app) in place of the 3rd party windows when they get minimized to dock. When my window (title bar only) gets double-clicked, I close my window and restore the real window from the dock.

My custom app works perfectly, but there is a lot of application switching going on. I have optimized the switching between apps to be nearly seamless, but the fact remains that there is application switching going on every time a window title bar is double-clicked. The result of application switching is that menu bars switch back and forth, pallets of 3rd party apps hide themselves when my app takes focus, and the list goes on.

So, although I've built a concept app, this method isn't going to work as I'd like it to. Minimize-in-place needs to be implemented using some other method than building an Application, and I need help understanding how to do it.

[image: minimize-in-place demo app]

**What I know think I need to do. Suggestions and assistance welcome.**
I think I need to write a custom framework that replaces AppKit? This seems overwhelming even though I only need a super-tiny portion of the code to be overridden? i.e. the core _minimize function whatever that may be.

When a title-bar of 3rd party window is double-clicked, just clip to the title bar and let the rest of the system function as normal. On un-minimize (double click 2nd time), set clip back to full window.

Simple right?

Thanks for any assistance/suggestions,

Chris